# How to achieve a queue of object instances of jQuery modals, assuring only one instance is on per time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

I've a task of building a modal prompt, that's been simple so far describing its methods like "show", "hide" when it comes down just to DOM manupulation.

Now comes the hardship for me... Imagine we have a page on which there are several immediate calls to construct and show several modals on one page

```
//on page load:

$("browser-deprecated-modal").modal();
$("change-your-city-modal").modal();
$("promotion-modal").modal();
```

By default my Modal (and other libraries i tried) construct all of these modals at once and show them overlapping each other in reverse order - 
i.e $(promotion-modal) is on the top, while the 
$("browser-deprecated-modal") will be below all of them. that's not what i want, let alone overlapping overlays.

I need each modal to show up only when the previous one (if there'are any) has been closed. So, first we should see "browser-deprecated-modal" (no other modals underneath), upon closing it there must pop up the second one and so on.

I've been trying to work it out with this:

```
$.fn.modal = function(options) {

  return this.each(function() {              
    if (Modal.running) {
        Modal.toInstantiateLater.push({this,options});
    } else {
         var md = new Modal(this, options);
    }
});
}

destroy :function () {
   ....
  if (Modal.toInstantiateLater.length)
  new Modal (Modal.toInstantiateLater[0][0],Modal.toInstantiateLater[0][1]);
}
```

keeping a track of all calls to construct a Modal in a array and in the "destroy" method make a check of this array is not empty.
 but it seems awkward and buggy me thinks. 
i need a robust and clear solution. I've been thinking about $.Callbacks or $.Deferred, 
kinda set up a Callback queue

```
if (Modal.running) { //if one Modal is already running

   var cb = $.Callbacks();
   cb.add(function(){
      new Modal(this, options);
   });

} else { //the road is clear
  var md = new Modal(this, options);
}
```

and to trigger firing cb in the destroy method, but i'm new to this stuff and stuck and cannot progress, whether it's right or not, or other approach is more suitable. 
Besides, I read that callbacks fire all the functions at once (if we had more than one extra modal in a queue), which is not right, because I need to fire Modal creation one by one and clear the Callback queue one by one.

Please help me in this mess.

My code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zz9ccbLn/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got rid of the counter variable, as you can use `toInstantiateLater` to keep track of where you are, and only had to make a few changes.  Give this a try...

**Javscript**

```
function Modal(el, opts){        
    this.el = $(el);
    this.opts = opts;
    this.overlay = $("<div class='overlay' id='overlay"+Modal.counter+"'></div>");
    this.wrap = $("<div class='wrap' id='wrap"+Modal.counter+"'></div>");
    this.replace = $("<div class='replace' id='replace"+Modal.counter+"'></div>");
    this.close = $("<span class='close' id='close"+Modal.counter+"'></span>")

    if (Modal.running) {
        Modal.toInstantiateLater.push(this);
    }
    else {
        Modal.running = true;
        this.show();
    }
}

Modal.destroyAll = function() {
    Modal.prototype.destroyAll();
};

Modal.prototype = {

    show: function() {
        var s = this;
        s.wrap.append(s.close);
        s.el.before(s.replace).appendTo(s.wrap).show();
        $('body').append(s.overlay).append(s.wrap);
        s.bindEvents();
        Modal.currentModal = s;
    },


    bindEvents: function() {
        var s = this;

        s.close.on("click.modal",function(e){
            s.destroy.call(s,e);
        });
    },

    destroy: function(e) {
        var s = this;

        s.replace.replaceWith(s.el.hide());
        s.wrap.remove();
        s.overlay.remove();

        if (Modal.toInstantiateLater.length > 0) {
            Modal.toInstantiateLater.shift().show();
        }
        else {
            Modal.running = false;
        }
    },

    destroyAll: function(e) {
        Modal.toInstantiateLater = [];
        Modal.currentModal.destroy();
    }

}

Modal.running = false;
Modal.toInstantiateLater = [];
Modal.currentModal = {};

$.fn.modal = function(options) {

      return this.each(function() {              
        var md = new Modal(this, options);
    });
}

$("document").ready(function(){

    $("#browser-deprecated-modal").modal();
    $("#change-your-city-modal").modal();
    $("#promotion-modal").modal();

    $("#destroy-all").on("click", function() {
        Modal.destroyAll();
    });
});
```

**jsfiddle example**

http://jsfiddle.net/zz9ccbLn/4/

Comment: in my environement there can be any amount of Modal calls on the page, the programmers put them wherever they like and name them whatever they want,  and they (modals) don't know about each other existance, 
like for instance, some modals are subject to condition - #brower-old-modal can show up only in case if a user sees it in an outdated browser. Others show up on special occasions as well. 
Nesting solution would not be desirable here.

Comment: need to construct an independent $("any-stuff").modal() call, so all the mess with many instances will be processed inside the Modal object, not inside the call

Comment: Yep, I understand.  Just having a play to see if I can get something that will "just work".

Comment: Have a look over that.  It does what I believe you're looking for, with the "just works" element that I was looking for ;)

Comment: that's more like it. Thanks a lot! 

there's one more thing though, I want to have a static method to destroy a current running Modal and clear the Modals queue from outside, from ajax script for example. In this case I'll be only able to work with DOM appended elements, no instances references will be available, right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  It would be easy enough to create a `destroyAll()` method, or similar, if that would suffice.

Comment: yes, i just want to understand that in Modal.destroyAll() i'll be only able to manipulate DOM directly (http://jsfiddle.net/zz9ccbLn/3/) $(".wrap").remove(), etc and not object instances? i won't be able to get instances to work with in this static method?

Comment: A bit of jiggery-pokery fixes that problem.  I've updated the code and fiddle link.